# How to store and retrieve arraylist having byte array data from shared preferences?

Tags: android

- I am trying to save byte array data in arraylist which worked fine as,

  ```
              SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(FirstActivity.this);
              SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit=sPrefs.edit();

              for(int i=0;i<byteArrayList.size();i++)
              {
                  sEdit.putString("val"+i,byteArrayList.get(i).toString());
              }
              sEdit.putInt("size",byteArrayList.size());
              sEdit.commit();
  ```
- I am retrieving byte array data by using,

  ```
      SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ViewImagesActivity.this);

      myAList=new ArrayList<byte[]>();
      int size=sPrefs.getInt("size",0);

      for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
      {
          myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j,"")); // giving error for type mismatch for byte[] and string


      }
  ```
- please help me to sort out this issue..
- please tell me if any other way to store and retrieve for this.
- Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j,null).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Error shown because array list type of byte array

```
 myAList=new ArrayList<byte[]>();
```

and you add value of string so gives your error .

Comment: giving this error : The method add(byte[]) in the type ArrayList<byte[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @user3707205 change string to byte array

Comment: I got solution bro.. Thanks for your kind help also... thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store `String` in a `Byte` type list:

```
myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j,));
```

You can use `int` in place of `Byte`. There is a standard method `putInt` and `getInt` for storing and retrieving data in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Is it necessary to use Byte array? Can you use int array instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `add` method with a `byte[]` parameter. The reverse operation is performed with `String.getBytes` method, so change the relevant line of your code:

```
myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j,"").getBytes());
```

Comment: The answer was flagged as low quality. Perhaps you could explain how/why the code works to ensure its not deleted.

Comment: Oh, low quality? The one who asks the question gave me the thanks as it works, and just for not being verbose in my answer you say it is low quality? :D